# How to return the sum of the values for a given .csv file?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, parsing, csv

I have a .csv file like this, it has words and values:

```
string1, 102, 90, 23
string2, 89, 45, 21
...
hi, 1, 3, 5
example, 2, 0, 2
someone, 1, 1, 1
hope, 0, 0, 0
stringN, 923, 23892, 9292
stringnN-1, 2903, 49058, 4859
```

and a very large list of words like this:

```
lis__ = [[Hi this is an example, this site is nice!.],...,[I hope someone can help]]
```

How can I return the sum of the values for each word that appear in `lis__`. For the above instance the output will be this:

For the first sub list:

```
    [Hi this is an example, this site is nice!.]

In:
    hi, 1, 3, 5
    example, 2, 0, 2
    someone, 1, 1, 1
    hope, 0, 0, 0

Then add value one with value one, two with two and three with three:

Out:
[(3,3,7)]
```

Then for the second sublist and add value one with value one, two with two and three with three:

```
In:
    [I hope someone can help]
    hi, 1, 3, 5
    example, 2, 0, 2
    someone, 1, 1, 1
    hope, 0, 0, 0
out:
    [(1,1,1)]
```

And finally:

```
[(3,3,7),...,(1,1,1)]
```

Where `...` is an infinity of strings or tuples. Probably this task could be done with the `csv` module, any idea of how to aproach this?. Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
import csv
import re

class Score(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.lst = args

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(tuple(self.lst))

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        new = [self.lst[i] + other.lst[i] for i in range(3)]
        return Score(*new)


lis__ = [
    'Hi this is an example, this site is nice!.',
    'I hope someone can help',
]

# Build word_scores dictionary, keyed by word
word_scores = {}
with open('yourcsv.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        word_scores[line[0].lower()] = Score(*map(int, line[1:]))


# Loop over lis__, computing the total score for each element (elem_score),
#    append it to line_scores
line_scores = []
for elem in lis__:
    elem_score = Score(0,0,0)
    for word in re.split(r'[^\w]+', elem):
        try:
            score = word_scores[word.lower()]
            print("  Found: %s %s" % (word.lower(), score))
            elem_score += score
        except KeyError:
            pass
    print("%s : %s" % (elem_score, elem))
    line_scores.append(elem_score)

print
print "Line Scores:"
print line_scores
```

Output:

```
  Found: hi (1, 3, 5)
  Found: example (2, 0, 2)
(3, 3, 7) : Hi this is an example, this site is nice!.
  Found: hope (0, 0, 0)
  Found: someone (1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1) : I hope someone can help

Line Scores:
[(3, 3, 7), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Try changing `Score(*map(int, line[1:]))` to `Score(*map(float, line[1:]))` or `Score(*map(lambda x: int(float(x)), line[1:]))`

Comment: Sure sorry i just realize about the float. thank you very much for the help. I am trying to see how was the sum.

Comment: `lis__` should look like this:`lis__ = [
    ['Hi this is an example, this site is nice!.'],
    ['I hope someone can help']
]` Instead of one list. Is a list of lists. Any idea of how to proceed?.

Comment: If all the sublists are single elements, change `for word in re.split(r'[^\w]+', elem):` to `for word in re.split(r'[^\w]+', elem[0]):`